# LinkedStyle for the Word BuiltinStyles

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I am extending the capability of the Word report writing from VSTO to consider different languages. Therefore, instead of using the headings like "Heading 1" etc, I have used wdStyleHeading1 etc. I have built a function to assign the style to the heading. The problem is that the line 1 and line 2 below are overwriting each other. If I call the function first, I loose list number and If I call function second, I loose the format. Can you please explain where I am going wrong?

I have imported the necessary references.

```
   Call HeadingListLevel(wrdApp, 1)
    wrdApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
```

Below is the sub function

```
Sub HeadingListLevel(wrdApp As Object, HeadingLvl As Integer)
    'Dim wrdHeading As String
    Dim wrdHeadingNr As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ListTemp As Word.ListTemplate

    wrdHeadingNr = "%" & 1
    ListTemp = wrdApp.ListGalleries(Word.WdListGalleryType.wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1)

    For i = 1 To HeadingLvl
        If i > 1 Then
            wrdHeadingNr = wrdHeadingNr & "." & "%" & i
        End If
    Next i
    'wrdHeading = "Heading " & HeadingLvl
    With ListTemp.ListLevels(1)
        Select Case HeadingLvl
            Case 1
                .LinkedStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1 
            Case 2
                .LinkedStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2
            Case 3
                .LinkedStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading3
            Case 4
                .LinkedStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading4
            Case 5
                .LinkedStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading5
            Case 6
                .LinkedStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading6
            Case 7
                .LinkedStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading7
        End Select
        .NumberFormat = wrdHeadingNr
        .NumberStyle = Word.WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleArabic
    End With

    wrdApp.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(ListTemplate:=ListTemp)

    ListTemp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using German Language as interface to test the program.

Comment: You can always use the [edit] link at the end of your question to add further information, as well as change wording, etc.

Comment: I think your problem is this: ` With ListTemp.ListLevels(1)` You're always going to go to Case 1. I think you wanted `i` instead of 1? Does it then work better?

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister, missing variable was one issue. Again, the issue was also with the way I was assigning the style. In the end it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer myself. Below is the changes to the sub function. It worked well for me.

```
    Sub HeadingListLevel(wrdApp As Object, HeadingLvl As Integer)
    'Dim wrdHeading As String
    Dim wrdHeadingNr As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ListTemp As Word.ListTemplate


    wrdHeadingNr = "%" & 1
    ListTemp = wrdApp.ListGalleries(Word.WdListGalleryType.wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(5)

    For i = 1 To HeadingLvl
        If i > 1 Then
            wrdHeadingNr = wrdHeadingNr & "." & "%" & 1
        End If
    Next i
    'wrdHeading = "Heading " & HeadingLvl
    With ListTemp.ListLevels(HeadingLvl)
        Select Case HeadingLvl
            Case 1
                .LinkedStyle = wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal
            Case 2
                .LinkedStyle = wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2).NameLocal
            Case 3
                .LinkedStyle = wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading3).NameLocal
            Case 4
                .LinkedStyle = wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading4).NameLocal
            Case 5
                .LinkedStyle = wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading5).NameLocal
            Case 6
                .LinkedStyle = wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading6).NameLocal
            Case 7
                .LinkedStyle = wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading7).NameLocal
        End Select

        '.LinkedStyle = wrdHeading
        .NumberFormat = wrdHeadingNr
        .NumberStyle = Word.WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleArabic
        '.StartAt = 1
        '.ResetOnHigher = False
    End With

    wrdApp.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(ListTemplate:=ListTemp)

    ListTemp = Nothing
End Sub
```